# Installed Ubuntu Server - need to remote access

Tags: server, remote

Hi I installed Ubuntu server on a machine, it is a server machine hence the graphic card is very poor; its a VGA. I cant access all of my screen, can only see the top 70 %, i tried changing the resolution but that didn't help either.

Now I want to access my server from another machine like a remote desktop does in windows or some other option but i don't know which tools to install on my server and what should be the corresponding tools to use from the client machine. I also have a client running ubuntu client version.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your server remotely via a terminal. You'll need to install/configure OpenSSH on your server.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

On your client machine, you'll need software like PuTTY (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)

In PuTTY, simply type in the IP Address of the server. If your server is not on the same subnet as the client machine, you'll need to forward the appropriate ports (on your router) to the server.

Comment: Hi Krisstian thanks for responding ... i wanted the GUI interface .. my understanding is that putty will give me a prompt window?

Comment: @Megatron Yes, that is correct - it'll display the Linux terminal. Sorry, I thought you were referring to the server/terminal.